# Query DataTable column into List (or Array) of Integers

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, linq, datatable

I'm trying to query a DataTable to get the list of ID's (integers) that correspond to a specific criteria, such that I can then parse that list into a joined string that can be used as a filter on a DataView :

```
Dim dvFilteredList As New DataView(dtbList)
Dim existingSelections = (From dtr In dtbMain.AsEnumerable
                          Where dtr.Field(Of String)("Field1") = strField1Value _
                              And dtr.Field(Of String)("Field2") = strField2Value _
                              And dtr.Field(Of String)("Field3") = strField3Value _
                              And Not IsDBNull(dtr.Field(Of Integer)("SomeID"))
                          Select New With {.SomeID = dtr.Field(Of Integer)("SomeID")}).ToList
Dim strViewFilter As String = "[SomeID] NOT IN (" & String.Join(",", existingSelections) & ")"
dvFilteredList.RowFilter = strViewFilter
```

When I try to query the list of integer ID's into `existingSelections`, I get this exception :

> Cannot cast DBNull. Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a
> nullable type.

How can I query the qualifying ID's into a list (or array) that I can then parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Field` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-6.0#system-data-datarowextensions-field-1(system-data-datarow-system-string)) supports nullable types, so use it correctly:

```
AndAlso dtr.Field(Of Integer?)("SomeID").HasValue
```

(also use `AndAlso` instead of `And` everywhere for performance reasons)

Comment: Thanks @Tim but I'm not getting `.HasValue` as an attribute option for `dtr.Field(Of Integer)("SomeID")` ? "HasValue is not a member of 'EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)'" Also, not sure if the '?' after `Integer` is a typo or if it has a significance?

Comment: @AlanO'Brien, the `?` is what specifies that it is nullable. `Integer?` is shorthand for `Nullable(Of Integer)`. It is that `Nullable(Of T)` type that has the `HasValue` property. You should read up on nullable value types.

Comment: Thanks, both, apologies I had included the '?' originally but must have fat-fingered something somewhere else such that the property was not coming up on the intellisense - rekeyed it clean and it's working now, not sure what I did the first time, sorry...